# Expectation of product of more than two independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

I am trying to determine whether independence of random variables changes when multiplied with other, potentially dependent variables. The question isn't in a measure-theoretic context.

In particular, I have 3 random variables, which we can call A, B, C

A is independent of both B and C, but B and C are not independent. Is it true then that:

$$\mathbb{E}[ABC] = \mathbb{E}[A]\mathbb{E}[BC]?$$

If it's true, I would appreciate if someone could either show me a proof (preferably one for someone without a strong measure-theoretic probability background) or point me to one.

Thanks

Comment: Some friendly advise: you can talk about $A$ being independent of each of the variables $B$ and $C$ and you can also talk about $A$ being jointly independent of $B$ and $C$. These two are not equivalent. You cannot understand independence with intuition alone. I would strongly advise you to pick up measure theory as soon as possible, because independence cannot be understood without measure theory.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have discrete random variables so that we do not deal with integrals. First use the independence assumption:
$$
\mathbb E(ABC)=\sum_{a,b,c} abc P(A=a,B=b,C=c)=\sum_{a,b,c} abc P(A=a)P(B=b,C=c).
$$
And then use the following identity to get the result:
$$
\sum_{a,b,c} abc P(A=a)P(B=b,C=c)=\sum_{a} a P(A=a)\sum_{b,c} bc P(B=b,C=c)=\mathbb E(A)\mathbb E(BC).
$$